# referential integrity hibernate Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am working with Hibernate 4 and Spring 3.5 , so I want to do a delete operation in a table or entity, but a table has referential integrity with other tables. I want to know how I can know if a table has referential integrity,  thus I can delete the record or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a constraint and you are not aware and you try to delete a record that has a dependency to the other tables. You might get a `ConstraintViolation` Exception.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html

Anyhow, I suggest you to look at table relationships (in the database) and make sure there is no PK/FK relationship before deleting any record.

Also if you are using JPA entities, you might have relationships in the JPA level (`@OneToOne`, `@OneToMany`, ...)

Comment: I am using DataIntegrityViolationException of Spring for catching a exception, but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you look at this link, might help:
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-dataIntegrityviolationexception